# Python Subprocess stdout and communicate()[0] not printing output that terminal would

Tags: python, terminal, popen, subprocess

Here is my code.

```
import subprocess

bashCommand = "./program -s file_to_read.txt | ./awk_program.txt"
process = subprocess.Popen(bashCommand.split(), stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
output = process.communicate()[0]
output2 = process.stdout
print output
print output2
```

This bash command alone when used in terminal prints the output of the awk_program (which just prints to stdout). But in python, output prints nothing and output2 prints

```
<closed file '<fdopen>', mode 'rb' at 0x2b5b20>
```

What do I need to do to return the output?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use the option `shell=True` in `Popen()` to have pipes work.

Note that if you don't know exactly where the `Popen` input is coming from, then `shell=True` is a [security risk](http://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#frequently-used-arguments).

Also, you don't need to split `bashCommand` here. For example:

```
>>> import subprocess as sp    
>>> cmd = 'echo "test" | cat'
>>> process = sp.Popen(cmd,stdout=sp.PIPE,shell=True)
>>> output = process.communicate()[0]
>>> print output
test
```

Comment: That made it give some response from the program. But still not the same output as running that bashCommand in terminal

Comment: @chimpsarehungry: Perhaps the process outputs to stderr as well?

Comment: Maybe, but adding stderr=subprocess.STDOUT or stderr=subprocess.PIPE doesn't help

Comment: @chimpsarehungry Check out my edit. Does it work like that? Pipes and `subprocess` don't work exactly like you'd expect...

Comment: Thank you. It was the split that was my problem. Not sure why I had that in there anyways.

Comment: @chimpsarehungry [The docs](http://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#popen-constructor) make it seem like a list of tokens should work, and the token list does work in many cases, but it doesn't work like you'd expect with pipes. I think you are probably "supposed" to make two processes and use python to pipe data from one to the other, instead of having a `|` in your command list.